# Iterating through a NxN matrix to form words with specific rule

Tags: java, python, matrix

Recently I came across this interview question which has got me confused in terms of implementation:

"There is a `NxN` matrix (a sample shown below). From each point in the matrix you can go only forward(diagonally or normal but not backwards). So from `F` you can go only to `C,G,I,J,K` but not to `A,B,E`. Now I have to iterate through the matrix and form and pass string to a function called `Boolean_check_words(str)` which will return if the passed string is a word or not(I don't have to implement it). "

```
A B C D
E F G H
I J K L
M N O P
```

Now I know that from each point in the matrix there are 8 possible directions. Some of those maybe out of bounds(For edge letters) and some of them maybe illegal as per the rule. But I don't know how to implement this iteration.

**Note:** I have tagged this question with both Python and Java as implementation in any of these language will be helpful in terms of understanding.

Comment: "Now I know that from each point in the matrix there are 8 possible directions" "So from `F` you can go only to `C,G,I,J,K`" That's only 5 directions - so which is it? (And why aren't `C` and `I` going backwards?)

Comment: I don’t believe you can do that in finite time. In the sample matrix you would need to pass "AE", "AEB", "AEBE", "AEBEB" to `Boolean_check_words(str)`, and so forth indefinitely. Apart from that, use recursion as in backtracking algorithms.

Comment: @user2916886 please post your attempts at solving the problem yourself.

Comment: This question as stands seems like a request from others to write you code. Please add your attempts so far.

Comment: @AndyTurner I have no idea to where even start thats why I haven't posted my attempt. Also from each point you have to process all valid and allowed directions.

Comment: @CentAu I don't know where to start for this solution thats why I haven't posted any attempt

Answer (score 0):

Ok you want a start.

Here is what I would try to work on with.

```
def iterate(m):
    for row in range(0,4):
        for col in range(0,4):
            print(m[row-1][col+1]+
                  m[row][col+1]+
                  m[row+1][col-1]+
                  m[row+1][col]+
                  m[row+1][col+1])


mat=[
   ["A","B","C","D",""],
   ["E","F","G","H",""],
   ["I","J","K","L",""],
   ["M","N","O","P",""],
   ["", "", "", "", ""]
  ]

iterate(mat)
```

Comment: I know that doing +1 and -1 I can go to next elements but the problem is that not all directions are possible. Like in your code for row = 0 m[row-1] is an invalid index. Thats what confusing me as to how to iterate while keeping all the possible directions into consideration

Comment: @user2916886 thats why I extended the arrays edges with empty strings

Comment: @user2916886 you know a [-1] index will just give you the last element :)

Comment: @user2916886 so did this help or not?